# ajax issue with users on slow connection

Tags: php, ajax, performance

i have the same exact issue here
    [1]: [Dealing with clients behind slow connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170963/dealing-with-clients-behind-slow-connection/)

the ajax call works fine when fast internet users use my portal,
how ever it give empty response with 200 ok for success call back for users with slow internet connection

its not time out issue that i can handle in error call back, its a wired issue as the success callback is triggered with 200 ok and empty response

Don't know why this happen only for users with slow internet connection.

any ideas ?

Comment: what exactly are you  returning via ajax call to client ? if images, then you can use lazy load functionality. lazy load jquery api returns just the specified number of images at a moment(which can be configured)

Comment: i return normal html data

Comment: then, the best thing to do is to remove the unnecessary js lib from the target script, which are returned via ajax call. try using the minified(compressed copy) version of your js lib than the  development version, this will reduce the sise of your html data beging transferred to client via ajax call.

Comment: there are lot other things which can incorporate in your web page, to increase the performance

Comment: i don't have any js lib in the called script, only return normal generated html table

Comment: ajax calls should always be used to extract a part of html code and not the complete html page. if the html code your extracing is very big, then split the call across into multiple ajax calls only, ie., using lazy load technique. for eg, you can visit flipkart.com,when u make a serach for a product, data will be displayed only to which the user/client can see at a time, rest will be loaded/appended to current html code when scrolled downwards(this is done via Lazy Load)

Comment: i don't get your point, why i have to use lazy technique for updating simple div with html table ?

Comment: can u tell what are you returning, may one sample request data, i`ll say whats causing it to delay

Comment: Remember the below code works just fine for users with normal internet connection, issue happens only for whome have slow ones `code 
$arr = get_s($txtarea); // get_s() take about 10 sec to excute
$str = implode(',', $arr);
$string = shell_exec($command $str); // this take about 50 sec to excute
$table = parse_data_to_html($string);
echo $table;`

Comment: can u provide the html equivalent  response for the above code

Comment: `code
$theData = array();
foreach($html->find('#theTable tr') as $row) {
$rowData = array();
foreach($row->find('td.text') as $cell) {
    $rowData[] = $cell->innertext;
}
$theData[] = $rowData;
}
print_r($theData);`

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I've seen this happen to myself.

I'm going to pass back the db record ID, and check for that manually in the success callback, before actually proceeding with my work on the client side.

Seems odd that you have to double check things in the success callback, but I assume handling flakey network connections is not a huge priority for the jquery team.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a loading mask to the div, using before send function in Ajax, until the data is fetched successfully.... something like;

```
     jQuery.ajax({
                url: "yourscript.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',

                beforeSend: function() {
                    jQuery(".selector #overlay").show();
                },
                success: function(response) {
                   if (response > 0) {
                        jQuery(".selector #overlay").fadeOut(800);
                        // your code......


    `
```

and in your CSS add a spinner or similar to the #overlay element;

```
    #overlay{display: none; position:absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;width: 100%;height: 100%; background: rgba(207, 207, 207, 0.5) url(/assets/spinner.gif) center center no-repeat;}
```